# How to run all shiny code when using runApp()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a long shiny dashboard that works well. The dashboard wrangles the data, makes projections and produce different plots and tables. The dashboard has a button that using rmarkdown produce a pdf report.

I would like to produce this report automatically every day. I tried to do that creating and observer that renders the pdf file when the object `report` is `TRUE`. Then when I run the app I pass the parameter `report` as `TRUE`:

```
launch_app <- function(report = FALSE){
  library(shiny)
  shinyOptions(report = report)
  shiny::runApp("app.R", host = "0.0.0.0",  port = 1222, launch.browser = FALSE)
}

launch_app(report = TRUE)
```

My intention was to run this script with chron every day, making the report and then the app stops (the app is also running in a shiny server). The problem is that when you launch the app the code is not executed until the dashboard is opened in a browser. So, the report is only produced if I open the url.

Do you know how to run all code when running the app without opening the browser or a way to produce the pdf report?

Comment: why not just use a script that uses knitr to generate the RMarkdown report? I mean, if you're not interacting with your shiny dashboard and you need to automate that, then I can't see why use shiny at all.

Comment: Because the app has different plots and the data of one plot is used for calculation in other plots, etc. Take out all the structure of the app would be painful and I will have to maintain the app and the script. The dashboard is always running in a shiny server and users can interact with it.

Comment: I believe you can use `shiny::testServer` to control some server-side functions. Then, you can use session$setInputs to control UI inputs. However, `testServer` is mostly used to test single modules. I'm not sure what structure you're using.. Another alternative would be to use some headless browser tool, scripting a sequence of UI inputs (that would be the filters and wrangling you told us about) and finally "pressing" the button.

Comment: I suppose use `rvest` to interact with the already running version of the app and download the file from that. Launching a separate version of the dashboard for this seems sketchy.

Comment: I tried `testServer()` with no success. The report is done with all default filters and values, so no need to change the UI. I worked in that direction also using shinytest but it didn't work.

Comment: @cory `rvest`will not work. I used curl to open the app and I got the html, but all code is not executed.

Comment: @FrancescVE hard to tell why shinytest or rvest didn't work. For what it seems, shinytest would be very straightforward. Just open the app, run the button. Record those actions as a script, and that's it. What exactly did you try out?

Comment: @eduardokapp shinytest was closing the process before the pdf was rendered.